# Java Bubble sort Algorithm timer issues

Tags: java, algorithm, sorting, timer

I'm trying to check the efficiency of this java bubblesort algorithm with a counter and timer. The counter works fine but the timer seems to take into account how long it takes the user to type in the set of numbers to be sorted. I only want the timer to time how long the bubblesort algorithm takes to sort. Any tips or help would be highly appreciated :)

```
public class bubsort {

public static void main(String[] args) {
    int n, c, d, swap;
    Long startTimer;
    Scanner in = new Scanner(System.in);

    System.out.println("Input number of integers to sort");
    n = in.nextInt();

    int array[] = new int[n];
    int counter = 0;

    System.out.println("Enter " + n + " integers");

    for (c = 0; c < n; c++) {
        array[c] = in.nextInt();
    }

   startTimer = System.nanoTime();

    for (c = 0; c < (n - 1); c++) {

        for (d = 0; d < n - c - 1; d++) {
            counter++;
            if (array[d] > array[d + 1]) {
                swap = array[d];
                array[d] = array[d + 1];
                array[d + 1] = swap;

            }
        }
    }
    System.out.println(System.nanoTime() - startTimer + "ms");

            System.out.println("Sorted list of numbers");

    for (c = 0; c < n; c++) {
        System.out.println(array[c]);
    }
    System.out.println("Counter: " + counter);
```

Comment: Nanoseconds != milliseconds. Also, `System.nanoTime()` has no relation to wall time. Do not expect accurate results with that.

Comment: @ElliottFrisch What do you mean by "do not expect accurate results with that"? OP is measuring a *duration*, which is the precise use case for `nanoTime`.

Comment: @MarkoTopolnik I mean - Do not expect a precise and accurate nanosecond count. See this line from the [JavaDoc](http://docs.oracle.com/javase/7/docs/api/java/lang/System.html#nanoTime%28%29) - "This method provides nanosecond precision, but not necessarily nanosecond resolution (that is, how frequently the value changes) - no guarantees are made except that the resolution is at least as good as that of currentTimeMillis()"

Comment: This wouldnt compile given that `StartTimer` is declared within the loop scope. Are you sure that that is how your code is? PS: for the love of all that is holy do not start variable names with an uppercase

Comment: This actually compiled fine as I'm using global variables and yes I agree I shouldn't use upper case variable name but right about now I'm more concerned with the accurate output of the code :)

Comment: @ElliottFrisch OK, it's not *guaranteed*, but I definitely *expect* much more than `currentTimeMillis` accuracy---and I am consistently not being let down. `nanoTime`'s resolution is typically in the low microseconds.

Comment: @user3199973 You are using global variables? Well, why don't you say so--that's your problem, then. Your local variable declaration *shadows* the global var, which you dereference in the `println` statement.

Comment: I've made some changes, but no joy. Anything else you could recommend?

Answer (score 1):

Move the startTimer before your nested loop, but after the input loop.  Then recall that nanoTime gives ns not ms.  If you want milliseconds use System.currentTimeMillis().

Comment: Hi Teresa,

I have moved the start timer to where you suggested, which is where I had commented it out in my original post but it still has the same issue. But I'm wondering if maybe I'm  coding it in the wrong way. 

For example if I sort 4 numbers in the order 3 4 1 2, I expect each time I run the programme the output from the timer should be the same or am I using the wrong timer? Thank you

Comment: *How* different are the times? You're measuring *nanoseconds*, so you can't expect them to be exactly the same every time.

Comment: It varies I've used 4 integers 3 4 1 and 2 consistently. Times have varied from 245169 ns to 376517ns which is why I feel that the timings are inconsistent. To test, I've taken a bit long to type in the numbers that need sorting etc. But the code and advice given so far looks fine to me.

Comment: Do keep in mind that your CPU is doing other things as well.  A better test would generate a list of several thousand integers either randomly or sequentially and then shuffling them.  Test that several times and compare, then increase the size of the list and test again.  Does it increase the way you would expect?

Comment: Thank you Teresa, I agree however I opted not to generate random numbers so I could conduct a more controlled experiment creating my own test data. I just didn't fully understand how nanoTime and currentTimeMillis actually worked, assuming each time my results should be identical. But the answers have cleared that up for me. Thanks.